# Copy routes to new HttpContext

Tags: asp.net-core

I use the following code to create a new `DefaultHttpContext` and use it to render views to strings.

```
var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();

if (serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>() is { } accessor)
{
    accessor.HttpContext = httpContext;
}

var website = page.WebsitePageModel as WebsitePageModel;
var domain = website?.PrimaryDomain;
if (website != null && domain != null)
{
    httpContext.Request.Host = "host"
    httpContext.Request.Scheme = "https";
    httpContext.Request.Path = "/my-page"
}

httpContext.RequestServices = serviceProvider;
var routeData = httpContext.GetRouteData();
routeData.Routers.Add(new RouteCollection());
```

This works well until I try to render a view component that uses routes/endpoints, e.g.

```
string url = Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController");
```

The `url` will be null because the controller does not know any routes. How can I access the routes of my web application and copy them to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the route, I found another way, but I don't know if it helps you.

I get all registered routes using `IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider`：

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure
@inject IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider provider
@{
    var urls = provider.ActionDescriptors.Items
                .Select(descriptor => "/" + string.Join('/', descriptor.RouteValues.Values
                .Where(v => v != null)
                .Select(c => c.ToLower())
                .Reverse()))
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();
}
@foreach (var item in @urls)
{
    @item 
}
```